# Compare two array and if contains value change is_selected to true ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to compare the two models `mainArray` and `resultArray`. If `category_name` and `sub_category_name` are found to be same, the `mainArray` `is_selected` is to be changed to true. How can I achieve this? They both are models.

```
var mainArray : [Item] =   [
            {
                "category_name": "Wellness",
                "sub_category": [
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Health",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Psychedelics",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Meditation",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Nutrition",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Outdoors",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Medicine",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Mindfulness",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Fitness",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Weights",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Veganism",
                        "is_selected": false
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "category_name": "Hustle",
                "sub_category": [
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Tik Tok",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "ClubHouse",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Stocks",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Networking",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Small business",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Instagram",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Enterpreneurship",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Real Estate",
                        "is_selected": false
                    },
                    {
                        "sub_category_name": "Pitch practice",
                        "is_selected": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]



var resultArray : [Item] = [
      {
        "category_name": "Wellness",
        "sub_category": [
          {
            "sub_category_name": "Psychedelics"
          },
          {
            "sub_category_name": "Fitness"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "category_name": "Hustle",
        "sub_category": [
          {
            "sub_category_name": "ClubHouse"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

This is the Item Model

```
// MARK: - Item
class Item: Codable {
    let category_name: String
    let sub_category: [SubCategory]
   


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case category_name = "category_name"
        case sub_category = "sub_category"
    }

    init(categoryName: String, subCategory: [SubCategory]) {
        self.category_name = categoryName
        self.sub_category = subCategory
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
var mainArray : [Item] =   [{
```

makes no sense because the data is a JSON string rather than an array of `Item`.

Second of all it's a bit tricky to update an array in place because you might have to deal with value semantics.

This suggestion works even with structs. I changed the names to more *Swift-compliant* names

```
let main = """
[
       {
        "category_name": "Wellness",
        "sub_category": [ ...



let result = """
[
      {
        "category_name": "Wellness",
        "sub_category": [ ...
```

---

```
struct Category: Codable {
    let name: String
    var subCategories: [SubCategory]
   
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "category_name"
        case subCategories = "sub_category"
    }
}

struct SubCategory: Codable {
    let name: String
    var isSelected = false
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name = "sub_category_name" }
}


func select(main: inout [Category], from result: [Category]) {
    result.forEach { category in
        guard let mainCategoryIndex = main.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == category.name}) else { return }
        for subCategory in category.subCategories {
            guard let subCategoryIndex = main[mainCategoryIndex].subCategories.firstIndex(where: {$0.name == subCategory.name}) else { return }
            main[mainCategoryIndex].subCategories[subCategoryIndex].isSelected = true
        }
    }
}


do {
    var main = try JSONDecoder().decode([Category].self, from: Data(main.utf8))
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Category].self, from: Data(result.utf8))
    
    select(main: &main, from: result)
    print(main)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```